# Query multiple tables and return all rows from all tables merged on a joint column

Tags: sql

Given the 3 tables below, how would I produce the desired results?

**Table 1**

```
ID    Count A
-----------------
1           1
2           2
```

**Table 2**

```
ID    Count B
-----------------
1           3
3           4
```

**Table 3**

```
ID    Count C
-----------------
2           5
4           6
```

**Result**

```
ID    Count A    Count B    Count C
-----------------------------------
1           1          3 
2           2                     5
3                      4          
4                                 6
```

I've tried things like

```
select a.id, a.count_a, b.count_b, c.count_c
from a
full outer join b
    on a.id = b.id
full outer join c  
    on a.id = c.id
    or b.id = c.id
```

and

```
select id, count_a
from a
union
select id, count_b
from b
union
select id, count_c
from c
```

but I've come to the realization I have no idea how to do something that seems simple.

Comment: `on isnull(a.id, b.id) = c.id` is simpler and possibly more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your full outer join approach looks to be on the right track.  If you wanted to use a union approach, you would have to use pivoting logic with aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src = 'a' THEN count END) AS "Count A",
    MAX(CASE WHEN src = 'b' THEN count END) AS "Count B",
    MAX(CASE WHEN src = 'c' THEN count END) AS "Count C"
FROM
(
    SELECT id, count_a AS count, 'a' AS src FROM a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, count_b, 'b' FROM b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, count_c, 'c' FROM c
) t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Ooh, I didn't think of a pivot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See example. That is what you tried, with colalesce(...) for id.

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id,c.id) id, a.count_a, b.count_b, c.count_c
from a
full outer join b
    on a.id = b.id
full outer join c  
    on a.id = c.id
    or b.id = c.id
```

Output

| id | count_a | count_b | count_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 2 | null | 5 |
| 3 | null | 4 | null |
| 4 | null | null | 6 |

Or, with @Charlieface suggestion

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id,c.id) id, a.count_a, b.count_b, c.count_c
from a
full outer join b
    on a.id = b.id
full outer join  c  
    on isnull(a.id, b.id) = c.id
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rcBY1gvE)

Comment: thanks!  this is a very simple and elegant solution